# parallel application on android devices

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing

Can I write a parallel application on multicore android phones?
I am trying to divide the application in to threads and run each thread on a core , to speed up the application . 
Can I control threads distribution on cores ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I control threads distribution on cores ?

no, and you don't want to. you create threads as you need. let the OS / VM decide how to distribute across cores. the OS / VM engineers are smarter than us.

Comment: No, they're really not.  I have a far better idea of locality of my app than the OS people, because I know whats going on in a thread whereas they have to guess (which means they'll guess its a generic worker thread, which means they'll bind it to the same core as my main app if possible to take advantage of memory cache locality, which is totally wrong if you have truly parallel operations).  That's why high end OSes have always allowed the client to bind threads to individual processors.

Comment: Jeffrey , thank you for your answer but just like Gabe said I think I can speed up the application because I know what each thread do

Comment: you can set thread priorities. honestly, i'm no expert in parallel programming, so this is a little bit of talking out of my butt so to speak.